# Textarea multiline placeholder but every line has different style

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I want to do a placeholder as I have attached a photo below

[image]

I have tried a few way but they didn't work, Is there any way to do like that.

Comment: Can you post your code that you tried? Otherwise we don't have a base to  figure out what your problem really is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly simple to achieve that by using pseudo-css-classes for the placeholder:

```css
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    /* design first line here */      
    font-size: 2em;
}

textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder::after {
    /* design second line here */
    display:block;
    content:"Please note that we do not work...";
    font-style:italic;
    font-size: .6em;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Message" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Unfortunately, you have to repeat the code for all browsers, using commas won't work:

```
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder { code... }
textarea:-moz-input-placeholder { code... }
textarea::-moz-input-placeholder { code... }
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder { code... }
```

Comment: Oh, had a typo after -ms-input-placeholder, did you add the r to the end? @TolgaKısaoğulları

Comment: I already added 'r' but it didn't work, I think because of content property @tom.